# Unable to Store the image for the second time in to the firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I created a simple application in which the user can browse through his/her gallery and after selecting the image option for cropping the image appears for that I have used some image crop library which was available on GitHub.
All works fine I am able to crop the image and upload it after that image appears into the fire base storage, but when I try to upload the image for the second time with different image it doesn't get uploaded in the firebase storage and only the first uploaded image appears. Please help me anyone to do something with this code so that it could upload multiple images

***XML Layout for MainActivity.java***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="imgcrop.example.com.androidimagecrop.MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/uploadbutton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="UPLOAD IMAGE"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
package imgcrop.example.com.androidimagecrop;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton imageButton;
    private Button uploadButton;
    private  static  final  int Image_request=1;
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://androidimagecrop.appspot.com");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        //getting the reference of the views
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadbutton);
        onImageViewClick(); // for selecting an Image from gallery.
        onUploadButtonClick(); // for uploading the image to Firebase Storage.
    }

    protected  void onImageViewClick(){
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent  .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(intent,Image_request );
            }
        });

    }
    protected  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == Image_request && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            CropImage.activity(selectedImageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this);
                if (null != selectedImageUri) {
                    // Get the path from the Uri
                    String path = getPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
                    imageButton.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);

                }

        }
        if (requestCode==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result= CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
            {
               Uri resulturi=result.getUri();
                imageButton.setImageURI(resulturi);
                StorageReference filepath=  storageRef.child(resulturi.getLastPathSegment());
            }
            else
            {
                if(resultCode==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE)
                {
                    Exception error=result.getError();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private String getPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String res = null;
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            res = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return res;
    }

    protected void onUploadButtonClick(){

        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles/image");

                imageButton.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                imageButton.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = imageButton.getDrawingCache();
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

                UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putBytes(data);
                uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TASK FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Uploaded SucessFully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Uri downloadUrl =taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        String DOWNLOAD_URL = downloadUrl.getPath();

                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

But on changing the name of child reference which is in onUploadButtonClick() method, I am able to store different image 
[image]

Here is my firebase storage section. I have created a root folder under which all images should get stored
[image: root folder]

[image: images]

Comment: You want to overwrite your previous image?

Comment: No I want to store image differently

Comment: You want to upload same image twice or more?

Comment: No multiple images I should able to upload

Comment: I want to store multiple images

Answer (score 0):

replace
`storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles/image");` with
replace  `storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profiles/"+System.currentTimeMillis());`

Comment: Can u explain what will happen with this??

Comment: Everytime you will upload a file, it will have a unique name in firebase storage.

Comment: thank you show much its working now but images are getting stored with random numbers as name of image. is there anyway to  upload the image with name of the image it self so that i can identify images differently with their names.hoping u will provide some solution

Comment: You can extract the file name from the uri and pass it to your storageReference. But two images can have two names, so I won't advice you that. Don't forget to accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just provide different reference each time. For example use timestamp.